# Calling a function from another function with arguments

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner to javascript ! I am trying to call a function from another function inside the same script tags. When I do this without sending arguments it works fine but when i do that with arguments that another function is not called..

Here is what I am doing

```
function measurement_convert()
{
var mc = "Measurement Conversion";
    txt = "<h2>"  + mc + "</h2> <br><br>";

    txt +=
        "<form action='' method='post'>" +
        "Select Type <select name='conversion_type' onchange='loadXML('abcd')'> "+
                    "<option value='area'>Area</option>"+
                    "<option value='length'>Length</option>"+
                    "<option value='volume'>Volume</option>"+
                    "<option value='weight'>Weight</option>"+
                    "</select> <br><br>"
    document.getElementById("content_main_top").innerHTML=txt;
}
```

So, I am calling the function from `onchange` of this form.

And here's the another function

```
 function loadXML(var1)
 {
    document.getElementById("content_main_top").innerHTML=null;
    document.getElementById("content_main_bottom").innerHTML=null;
 }
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: When I change the select option the `loadXML(var)` function is not called indeed nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your single quotes are clashing in the onchange value, as you use the same for closing the value in.

You can change it to:

```
"Select Type <select name='conversion_type' onchange=\"loadXML('abcd')\"> "
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are trying to nest the same type of quote:

```
onchange='loadXML('abcd')'
```

This actually gets interpreted as:

```
onchange='loadXML('
```

Instead, try (note the escaped double-quotes, since this code is inside a PHP string):

```
Select Type <select name=\"conversion_type\" onchange=\"loadXML('abcd')\">
```